# Why are Quantity and Units inconsistent with regular Mathematica behavior?

Tags: units, language-design

When I enter this in Wolfram Mathematica V12:

```
0 Dogs + 5 Cats
```

Mathematica sensibly returns this:

```
5 Cats
```

BUT, if I using the Units and Quantity features
in Mathematica V12, and enter this:

```
0 m + 37 m/s
```

Or in long form:

```
Quantity[0, "Meters"] + Quantity[37, "Meters"/"Seconds"]
```

I get:

```
 Quantity::compat: Meters/Seconds and Meters are incompatible units
```

I know the units are not compatible, but ZERO "Meters" is just 0
and should logically disappear from the equation just as "0 Dogs"
disappears from the first example.

This **bug** breaks most symbol differentiation and integration.

I guess Wolfram really screwed up by not making Units part of V1
back in the 1980's, and instead added it as a **glued on bag**, in
V12. Talk about "creeping featurism" ;-)

BTW, the only means I have found of controlling this horrible
Mathematica functionality is with pages of ugly substitution rules
like this:

```
removeUnitsOfZeroMagnitude[myExpression_] := Module[{},
  myExpression /. Quantity[0, "Meters"] -> 0 /. 
     Quantity[0, "Meters"/"Seconds"] -> 0 /. 
    Quantity[0, "Meters"/"Seconds"^2] -> 0 /. 
   Quantity[0, "Meters"/"Seconds"^3] -> 0
  ]
```

Of course, this ugly hack makes simple one line calculations,
that were so beautiful and elegant in V4, now many lines of
nasty, unreadable   code.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is Mathematica V4 still for sale?

Thanks,

- Joe

### Example

Here is a more detailed image of the errors I am receiving in Mathematica V12 when trying to evaluate a simple integral. It seems to me in an evaluation like Times or Plus, or whatever, expressions of Units with ZERO magnitude should be removed, as one would do with simple pen and paper.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could provide an actual example where you encounter this issue. In principle, differentiating a valid expression should again yield a valid expression

Comment: Why do you think this behaviour is sensible? What about this `1m` + (`-1m` + `37m/s`)? Zero quantity should still be a part of space it belongs to and not just disappear, this breaks a lot of math stuff. If this expression comes from some computation then most certainly this computation is wrong.

Comment: Please provide the actual Mathematica code for this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpDKz.jpg . (The one edited my answer with.)

Comment: Using replacement rules you only need one to remove zero quantities: `Quantity[0|0., ___] :> 0`

Comment: This works btw: `Integrate[v t, Quantity[t, "Seconds"]]`. So maybe define your time as `t = Quantity[\[FormalT], "Seconds"]`

Comment: Again: copy and paste your Mathematica code here, do not just post screenshots.

Comment: What type of physical system are you trying to model where it makes sense to add meters and meters per second?  Or dogs and cats for that matter?

Comment: @JasonB I have added apples and oranges, and even pears with considerable success. It was an excellent sangria...

Comment: Voting to close. Questioning design decisions falls very much into the "opinion based" closure category, and this does not have a clear Mathematica question that can be answered.

Comment: I'd just like to second what @JasonB. is saying. If your differentiation/integration code is trying to add inconsistent units, your differentiation is simply wrong. The message is telling you something and you ignore it at your peril.

Comment: Here is a related discussion: ["Is Quantity necessary?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114865)

Comment: Even on paper numbers should not just disappear. The result of the integral should have the same units as the other numbers, so you're adding 0 m + 37 m, not numbers with different units. I do think the fact that `Integrate["0 m/s^2", t] = "0 m/s^2"` and `"0 m/s^2" Integrate[1, t] = t("0 m/s^2")` is problematic. Since I think this only happens when integrating a constant of 0, you can pull it out of the integral: `a Integrate[1, t, t]`, or use explicit integration limits as workarounds.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - I’d like the opportunity to answer this question. The simple solution to integrating constants is to leave them undefined, integrate the expression, and substitute the constants into the integral. But the underlying issue is result of a zero-quantity in integration, such as `\[Integral]\[Integral]Quantity[0.,"Meters"/"Seconds"^2]\[DifferentialD]t\[DifferentialD]t` versus `\[Integral]\[Integral]HoldForm[Quantity[0.,"Meters"/"Seconds"^2]]\[DifferentialD]t\[DifferentialD]t`. In the first integral, the `t^2` term disappears. This missing term causes the Quantity mismatches.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - Where does this lead? `HoldForm` with `r0`, `v0` and `a`, and `ReleaseHold` after the integral solves the problem.

Comment: @creidhne You may be interest in providing an answer to [OP’s follow up question on this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235588/27951) then. That one contained an answerable problem.

Comment: @MarcoB - Thank you. The new question is a specific issue; it’s an X-Y problem where my answer doesn’t apply. I’ll let this one stand as is. I appreciate your follow-up.

Comment: @creidhne Curious to see your answer! I voted to reopen.

Comment: I avoid `Quantity[]` as much as possible but this seems ok, no?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e7B4.png

Comment: I doubt that you really want V4, but you may want this:  https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/5511/  .  I still use it. I do not know why they threw away the `Convert` command. I only use the newer versions if I am copying someone else's examples.  You can browse the infocenter for all kinds of stuff that still works,  although a lot doesn't.

Answer (score 19):

*Not a solution but an extended comment.*

You misunderstand the physical underpinnings of quantities and units.

Every physical quantity has an inherent margin of error, even if it is very small (negligible) and thus tacitly suppressed. The quantity **1 meter** truly means **approximately 1 meter, give or take a few millimeters/nanometers/Planck distances**.

The quantity **0 meters** means **a distance that is consistent with zero within the margin of my measurement's error**. This error margin carries units, even if the mean value is precisely zero. So we cannot cancel out the units, and **0 meters** is not equal to **0 apples** or **0 seconds**. [Democritus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democritus) had already pretty much figured this out 2500 years ago.

Mathematically, we observe that the point 0 is of zero measure on the real axis, and is the only point $x$ where **$x$ meters** could be said to be equal to **nothing**. But physical quantities refer to *intervals*, not *points*, on the real axis, and therefore the unit can never be cancelled out in the way you suggest.

Mathematica's behavior in this matter is thus completely expected and normal.

Comment: Please ;-) I appreciate the technical cuteness, but you are missing the key point about simple mathematical behavior. The kind of basic mathematical example, as one might work on a piece of paper. You have to admit that the dog/cat example is a contradiction in basic behavior with the integral example. As a CS guy, I consider this a fundamental flaw in the overall design of Matheamtica. It is inconsistent. And the dog/car behavior is the only sensible one.

Comment: Again, `Quantity[0, "Meters"]` is not the mathematical zero but represents an interval of unknown (but probably small) size around zero. Mathematica treats it as such, which is sensible.

Comment: Since I can't post an answer....As a mathematician, I don't agree that you cannot represent an exact number of units. I would assert `Quantity[0, "m"]` does this, whereas `Quantity[0., "m"]` with a `Real` scalar represents an approximate amount. Conceptually (to me), `Quantity[x, "m"]` lives in a 1D vector space $\langle u\rangle$ generated by $u=$ `"m"` that is disjoint from other vector spaces $\langle u'\rangle$ with different units. There is a unique bilinear product on the collection unit spaces, which includes dimensionless scalars, fixed by $1u_1\times 1u_2=1(u_1\times u_2)$....

Comment: As for a sum of quantities, which is not as ridiculous as other commenters make appear — consider "bundles of goods" in rational choice theory in economic — the question is how to represent a sum of quantities such as five cats plus four dogs. The standard representation is the direct product (or direct sum) of unit vector spaces, which is a Cartesian product when finite and in Mathematica would be represented by a vector `List`. The `Plus` representation the OP presents is in effect a disjoint sum of the unit spaces. I don't think `Plus` was designed to do this.

Comment: There are gaps, like the distributive law: `0. (Quantity[1, "m"] + Quantity[2, "m/s"])` vs. `0. Quantity[1, "m"] + 0. Quantity[2, "m/s"]`. As I said, I don't think `Plus` was designed to do this.

Comment: @MichaelE2 WR has chosen the physicist's view of units, not the mathematician's; you can agree or disagree with this choice. There are advantages and disadvantages on both ends, and choices need to be made. In the physicist's view, adding two objects with different units is a "syntax error" and makes no sense. If you want to define a mathematician's addition operation that accommodates divergent units, that's fine; but that's not how physical units work. Physical units have a real-world correspondence to satisfy (through the measurement process) and cannot be redefined ad lib.

Comment: "WR has chosen the physicist's view of units" -- Have they really? Reference? Especially concerning `Quantity[1, "m"]` representing an approximate quantity. To me `Quantity[]` works exactly according to the mathematical conception of a unit being a distinguished basis vector. I'm not suggesting that one can meaningfully add quantities with distinct units. I think we agree on that. In the math view, vectors can be added only when from the same vector space. Where we disagree is whether a "margin of error" model or a "distinct vector space" model explains it, and whether quantities can be exact.

Answer (score 11):

> Is Mathematica V4 still for sale?

This answer proposes less drastic solutions than moving back for Version 4.

### "Global" solution

For the problems you encounter and approach you take one -- not that good -- proposal is to redefine `Quantity`:

```
Unprotect[Quantity];
(*Quantity[x_,___]:=x;*)
Quantity[0, ___] := 0;
Protect[Quantity];
```

**Remark 1:** I have not checked or used the code above extensively -- it put it more as a "I share your pains" statement, and, sort of, to encourage other posts proposing solutions in that style.

**Remark 2:** With `Quantity[x_,___]:=x;` you can "remove" the `Quantity` functionalities from most computations. But that is also dangerous, because some built-in functions do rely on `Quantity` working properly. For example, `WeatherData` or `FinancialData`. Personally, 95% of the time  after ingesting `data` with those functions I use `data /. Quantity[x_, _] :> x`.

[image]

### Evaluation with `Quantity` re-defintion

Consider using this function instead of the "global" approach above (and/or your `removeUnitsOfZeroMagnitude`):

```
Clear[RemoveQuantity]
SetAttributes[RemoveQuantity, {HoldFirst}];
RemoveQuantity[myExpression_] := Block[{Quantity = #1 &}, myExpression];
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the clever response, but I think you will agree, that they are not really solutions. One, overloading the function name, is likely to make the whole Mathematica system unstable. And the second idea, of just removing the units entirely defeats the purpose of having units in the first place, no?

Comment: `Quantity[...]/.Quantity[x_, _]:>x` can just be done with `QuantityMagnitude`

Comment: @FrancisBush Yes, you are correct on both points. As I mentioned in my answer, I posted it mostly to express solidarity with your frustrations over `Quantity`. I do find the quantity family of functionalities too intrusive, and I did/do spend non-trivial amounts  time to deal with unwanted outcomes caused by them.

Comment: I don't think adding a definition for `Quantity[0,___]` is likely to make the whole system unstable. As noted in the question, the Quantity stuff is an add-on, not part of the core of Mathematica, so this seems like a safe change.