# Differences of Quantities gives different result in different Mathematica version

Tags: units

In Mathematica 12.2

```
Differences[{Quantity[1, "mm"], Quantity[1, "mm"]}]
```

gives

```
{Quantity[0, "Millimeters"]}
```

In Mathematica 13.1, same expression gives

```
{0}
```

with no unit!

This introduces inconsistency. For example

```
StandardDeviation@
 Differences[{Quantity[1, "mm"], Quantity[1, "mm"], Quantity[2, "mm"],
    Quantity[3, "mm"]}]
```

prompts errors in 13.1, while no problem in 12.2

In the documentaion of `Differences`, it says

> Differences[list] is equivalent to ListConvolve[{1,-1},list].

But it is not!

```
ListConvolve[{1, -1}, {Quantity[1, "mm"], Quantity[1, "mm"]}]
```

gives

```
{Quantity[0, "Millimeters"]}
```

What is changed for `Differences` in 13.1? It seems like a bug. Are there some other side effects of this potential change?

**Update**

A patch I can think of is

```
Unprotect[Differences]
Differences[x : {__Quantity}] := ListConvolve[{1, -1}, x];
Protect[Differences]
```

But I do not know if Unprotect and Protect a built-in function will have undesirable side effect or not. Anyone knows?

Comment: As a workaround, `Differences[list] /. {0 -> Quantity[0, QuantityUnit[list[[1]]]]}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for comment. I just add my workround in my post. But I do not know if it is proper or not

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. `0 mm` is definitely not the same as `0`, [see here for an extended comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235567/26598).

Comment: Minimal example: compare `Quantity[1, "Millimeters"] - Quantity[1, "Millimeters"]` with `Subtract[Quantity[1, "Millimeters"], Quantity[1, "Millimeters"]]`

Comment: @JasonB. So we need one more patch for `Subtract`. I even guess `Subtract` and `Differences` are related in the internal.