# Adding `Subtract` definition affects performance of BoolEval function

Tags: performance-tuning

Due to some bug shown in [Differences of Quantities gives different result in different Mathematica version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/271089/4742), I add an additional definition to `Subtract`. But I found it will severely slow down Szabolcs' [BoolEval](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BoolEval/) function.

A fresh Mathematica kernel, run

```
array = RandomReal[1, 1000000];
Pick[array, ResourceFunction["BoolEval"][array > 0.5], 
   1]; // RepeatedTiming
```

gives

```
{0.0163395, Null}
```

Another fresh Mathematica kernal, run

```
Unprotect[Subtract];
Subtract[x_Quantity, y_Quantity] := x - y;
Protect[Subtract];
array = RandomReal[1, 1000000];
Pick[array, ResourceFunction["BoolEval"][array > 0.5], 
   1]; // RepeatedTiming
```

gives

```
{0.521434, Null}
```

Why does adding an additional definition affect so much? What is more, how to fix `Subtract` quantity bug without affecting `BoolEval`?

**update**

Now I know how to fix `Subtract` quantity bug without affecting `BoolEval`. In the `BoolEval` package, replace all `Subtract[a,b]` and similar with `a-b`, then it will not affected by new definition of `Subtract`. But I still do not know why adding an additional `Subtract` definition affect so much?

Comment: This is related, I guess: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thank you so much for your link. I forgot `Subtract` is faster than `-`. That is why `BoolEval` package use `Subtract`. And that makes my updated fix not perfect in terms of performance. Sad : (

Comment: How does `Unprotect[Quantity];
Quantity /: Subtract[x_Quantity, y_Quantity] := x - y;
Protect[Quantity];` instead behave?

Comment: @CarlWoll Work like a charm! Thank you so much!